# Right-clicking on an element at specific x and y coordinates - Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to right-click on an element at a certain location (the element itself will change as I scroll through the page, I want to click in the same location as I scroll). I have searched through Selenium's documentation and have struggled to find a way to right-click on a certain location on the webpage. I am currently able to move to a certain location using:

```
actionChains.move_by_offset(1075, 85)
```

Is there any way to right-click at this specific coordinate (Not sure if it involves implementing context_click or another method)? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

U can do this: Identify the body of the page and move the mouse to the coordinates that u wanna click. Then, invoke the right-click function, like:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

body = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')

action = ActionChains(driver)

x_offset = 1000
y_offset = 500

action.move_to_element_with_offset(body, x_offset, y_offset)

actionChains.context_click(body).perform() #Right clicks
```

Hope that this helps!

Comment: I tried this, and didn't find it to work for me. However, after conducting research, I realized that using actionchains.key_down(Keys.CONTROL) and then using actionchains.click() works. Thank you!